# WWW-Mechanize-1.71 install error on test nonascii.t

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am getting an install error when installing WWW-Mechanize-1.71 on perl 5.8.8 running on OSX

The error is:

t/local/nonascii.t ....... 1/5 No such field 'ValueOf'CF.{Ñ}'' at /WWW-Mechanize-1.71/blib/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 1407

Any hints on how I should debug this?

Comment: Test results for WWW::M 1.71 from other people on darwin with Perl 5.8.8: http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=WWW-Mechanize%201.71;reports=1;os=darwin;perl=5.8.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the unpacked directory. If you want to start over, either run the CPAN shell and issue the `look` command

```
$ cpan
cpan> look WWW::Mechanize
```

… or if you have cpanminus, run it with the `--look` option:

```
$ cpanm --look WWW::Mechanize
```

---

```
WWW-Mechanize-1.71$ perl Makefile.PL; make
WWW-Mechanize-1.71$ prove -bv t/local/nonascii.t
```

`prove` in verbose mode will make clear exactly which test is failing.

```
WWW-Mechanize-1.71$ perl -d -Mblib t/local/nonascii.t
```

Step through with the Perl debugger to find the cause of the failure.